# Obtener código de idioma del dispositivo para cargar tabla MySql multi-idioma

Tags: android

Tengo una tabla MySql multi-idioma la cual cargo en un recyclerView con Volley y Glide[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por default Android carga los strings que estan "dentro" de la app (values-fe, values-en ...) 
de acuerdo al idioma del dispositivo, pero no las bases de datos por lo que
necesito saber si hay alguna forma de obtener el código de idioma y así
cargar de la tabla solo las columnas con el idioma correspondiente.

Estos métodos no dan el **código** de idioma que, por ejemplo en inglés es "en":

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(); //English
Locale.getDefault().toString();           //en_US
Locale.getDefault().getISO3Language();    //eng
```

En el emulador al cambiar de idioma hay que seleccionar el país.
Puedo usar este otro método que si me lo cambia a inglés solo si la 
localización del dispositivo esta en USA, pero si esta por ejemplo en Australia no.

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
new Locale("en","US")
```

Este es el código que carga solo las tablas correspondientes al idioma
seleccionado. Manualmente si manipulo la variable `lan` lo hace
correctamente.

```
final String lan= "";
JsonArrayRequest aarRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL +"/porcionesall.php",              
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (response.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Phpdato item = new Phpdato();
                        item.setId(data.getString("id"));
                        item.setAlim(data.getString(lan+"_alimento"));
                        item.setPorcion(data.getString(lan+"_porcion"));
                        item.setThubnail(URL + data.getString("foto"));  //en MySql: /img/nombredelarchivo.jpg
                        listdata.add(item);
                        recyclerAdapterPhp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                    }
```

Comment: Puedes obtenerlo así: `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [`getLanguage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage()) te devuelve el código del lenguaje según [la norma ISO 639](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) (2ª columna).

Por ejemplo:

```
String codLenguaje=Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

### Prueba:

```
Log.d(TAG,codLenguaje);
```

En mi dispositivo, dejando **el idioma**, no la región, como estaba (Español) y luego poniéndolo a Inglés (Reino Unido), Francés, Italiano. La salida en el log es esta en los diferentes casos:

```
01-21 20:18:41.800 27455-27455/org.deiverbum.app D/TestActivity: es
01-21 20:22:27.180 28708-28708/org.deiverbum.app D/TestActivity: en
01-21 20:23:16.550 28708-28708/org.deiverbum.app D/TestActivity: fr
01-21 20:24:09.310 28708-28708/org.deiverbum.app D/TestActivity: it
```

Comment: Así es. Al igual que con: getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();