# Mostrar un contenido u otro dependiendo del Json - Libreria GSON

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, gson

Buenas tengo unas dudas de como obtener ciertos parametros de un JSON, desde la libreria GSON. Y dependiendo que paramentros tenga, mostrara un contenido u otro del JSON.

**Aqui tengo mi JSON.**

```
{
  "decimalHola": 94.55,
  "boleanoHola": true,
  "enteroHola": 123,
  "idiomas": [
    {
      "en": {
        "msg_Fallo": {
          "titulo": "[EN] Titulo",
          "mensaje": "[EN] Mensaje blablabla"
        },
        "msg_Correcto": {
          "titulo": "[EN] Titulo",
          "mensaje": "[EN] Mensaje blablabla"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "es": {
        "msg_Fallo": {
          "titulo": "[ES] Titulo",
          "mensaje": "[ES] Mensaje blablabla"
        },
        "msg_Correcto": {
          "titulo": "[ES] Titulo",
          "mensaje": "[ES] Mensaje blablabla"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "mensajeHola": "Hello World33355"
}
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer es una vez se carga la aplicación obtenga el idioma nativo del móvil y así mostrarle los mensajes de validaciones en su respectivo idioma. El problema es que no se como puedo obtener únicamente el valor dependiendo del dispositivo. Por ejemplo si el dispositivo es [EN], sacar todos los mensajes relacionados con el Idioma [EN], evidentemente el [ES] no nos haría falta por el momento. ¿Como debo de hacer la comprobaciones correctamente y mostrar el idioma correspondiente con sus Validaciones de Fallos/Correcto y sus mensajes de "titulo" y "mensaje".

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String json = response.body().string();
                String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(); //Obtenemos el Idioma del Dispositivo
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                final Dat_json datoson = gson.fromJson(json, Dat_json.class);
            // datoson -> Contiene todo el JSON, pero necesitamos saber que idioma debemos mostrarle


            } else {
                Log.d("ERROR",response.body().string());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

> Aquí están las Clases correspondientes:

**Dat_json.class**

```
public class Dat_json {
    @SerializedName("decimalHola")
    public double getDecimalHola() {
        return this.decimalHola;
    }
    public void setDecimalHola(double decimalHola) {
        this.decimalHola = decimalHola;
    }
    private double decimalHola;

    @SerializedName("boleanoHola")
    public boolean getBoleanoHola() {
        return this.boleanoHola;
    }
    public void setBoleanoHola(boolean boleanoHola) {
        this.boleanoHola = boleanoHola;
    }
    private boolean boleanoHola;

    @SerializedName("enteroHola")
    public int getEnteroHola() {
        return this.enteroHola;
    }
    public void setEnteroHola(int enteroHola) {
        this.enteroHola = enteroHola;
    }
    private int enteroHola;

    @SerializedName("idiomas")
    public List<Idioma> getIdiomas() {
        return this.idiomas;
    }
    public void setIdiomas(List<Idioma> idiomas) {
        this.idiomas = idiomas;
    }
    List<Idioma> idiomas;

    @SerializedName("mensajeHola")
    public String getMensajeHola() {
        return this.mensajeHola;
    }
    public void setMensajeHola(String mensajeHola) {
        this.mensajeHola = mensajeHola;
    }
    private String mensajeHola;

}
```

**Idioma.class**

```
public class Idioma {
    @SerializedName("en")
    public En getEn() {
        return this.en;
    }
    public void setEn(En en) {
        this.en = en;
    }
    En en;

    @SerializedName("es")
    public Es getEs() {
        return this.es;
    }
    public void setEs(Es es) {
        this.es = es;
    }
    Es es;
}
```

**En.class**

```
public class En {
    @SerializedName("msg_Fallo")
    public MsgFALLO getMsg_Fallo() {
        return this.msg_Fallo;
    }
    public void setMsg_Fallo(MsgFALLO msg_Fallo) {
        this.msg_Fallo = msg_Fallo;
    }
    MsgFALLO msg_Fallo;

    @SerializedName("msg_Correcto")
    public MsgCORRECTO getMsg_Correcto() {
        return this.msg_Correcto;
    }
    public void setMsg_Correcto(MsgCORRECTO msg_Correcto) {
        this.msg_Correcto = msg_Correcto;
    }
    MsgCORRECTO msg_Correcto;
}
```

**Es.class**

```
public class Es {
    @SerializedName("msg_Fallo")
    public MsgFALLO getMsg_Fallo() {
        return this.msg_Fallo;
    }
    public void setMsg_Fallo(MsgFALLO msg_Fallo) {
        this.msg_Fallo = msg_Fallo;
    }
    MsgFALLO msg_Fallo;

    @SerializedName("msg_Correcto")
    public MsgCORRECTO getMsg_Correcto() {
        return this.msg_Correcto;
    }
    public void setMsg_Correcto(MsgCORRECTO msg_Correcto) {
        this.msg_Correcto = msg_Correcto;
    }
    MsgCORRECTO msg_Correcto;
}
```

**MsgFALLO.class**

```
public class MsgFALLO {
    @SerializedName("titulo")
    public String getTitulo() {
        return this.titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    String titulo;

    @SerializedName("mensaje")
    public String getMensaje() {
        return this.mensaje;
    }
    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }
    String mensaje;
}
```

**MsgCORRECTO.class**

```
public class MsgCORRECTO{
    @SerializedName("titulo")
    public String getTitulo() {
        return this.titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    String titulo;

    @SerializedName("mensaje")
    public String getMensaje() {
        return this.mensaje;
    }
    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }
    String mensaje;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la estructura de la clase `Dat_json`? Y ¿qué código implementas para saber el idioma del dispositivo? Tendrías que saberlo para en base a eso buscar la clave en el JSON. Y además implementar una posibilidad en caso de que sea algo no contemplado en tu estructura, por ejemplo, si el idioma está en chino, la estructura que presentas no tiene esa posibilidad y el código debe manejarlo o la app hará crash.

Comment: He revisado tu publicación donde aclarabas ciertas cosas de GSON con el ejemplo del SalmoCompleto();, pero me cuesta entenderlo. He actualizado el contenido y he añadido todas las clases del JSON, puedes echarle un vistazo. Y la verdad es que falta la posibilidad de saber en que idioma viene el dispositivo. Como mencionas si viene en Chino la APP haría crash. Lo ideal es que si no esta el idioma dentro del JSON que muestre por defecto el ingles, por ejemplo. Gracias de antemano @A.Cedano

Comment: Precisamente ahí es donde empiezas a sacar un provecho interesante a Gson, porque toda esa lógica complicada la puedes implementar en la clase (es el mismo ejemplo que ponía en la respuesta que refieres donde hablo de `SalmoCompleto`). En tu caso, en la lógica de la clase se podría recibir el parámetro del idioma, cualquiera que sea, buscarlo en un array o en un mapa y si no se encuentra, asignar uno por defecto... Dicho eso, no termino de ver claro cómo se conectan ambas situaciones en tu contexto, es decir, no logro entender  la manera en la que piensas pasar el idioma del dispositivo...

Comment: En el **MainActivity.class** he declarado lo siguiente `String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`, aquí es donde sabemos el idioma que tiene el dispositivo. Una vez obtenido el idioma del dispositivo, la idea es que busque si es el idioma Español [ES] dentro del JSON y que únicamente muestre los mensajes de ese idioma. _(Supongo que es a esto a lo que te refieres @A.Cedano)._

Comment: Sí, a eso me refiero. Pero en este caso olvídate del JSON. Es en tu modelo de datos donde tienes que conectar las cosas. O sea, en tu modelo de datos no veo ningún método que reciba a `language` (obtenido del dispositivo) y allí determine si existe o no y si no existe que asigne el inglés por defecto. No sé si me explico. En la lógica de tu App no veo cómo le pasas el idioma del dispositivo. Todo lo demás es pan comido, es eso lo que tienes que resolver ahora: **meter a jugar ese dato en el modelo de datos**. Dicho de otro modo, ¿qué clase/método recibe el idioma?

Comment: `language` no esta definido. Solo que en **MainActivity.class** creo la variable `language` para contener el idioma. Habia pensado en hacer un Switch() y que vaya entrando por Casos: ES, EN o Default. pero el problema es que no se como puedo compararlo. Ademas no te entiendo con lo que me estas preguntando si la clase/método recibe idioma?...

Comment: O sea, el problema que yo veo es que una vez recuperas el idioma del dispositivo, tienes que pasarlo al modelo de datos para que éste determine lo que hay que hacer en base al dato que se le pasó. Si el dispositivo está en chino, el modelo de datos buscará el idioma chino (porque implementaste una lógica para ello dentro del modelo) y al no encontrarlo, asignará el idioma por defecto. El problema es que eso no  está reflejado en la lógica que estás implementando. O sea, el dato que obtienes del dispositivo no tienes implementado cómo meterlo dentro del modelo de datos, ese es el problema.

Comment: Habias hecho una pregunta similar hace uno par de días, en mi respuesta estaba como modelar las clases para Gson y como acceder a los mensajes. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/246576/como-puedo-leer-el-objecto-dentro-de-un-json-utilizando-gson/246612#246612

Comment: @Juan el problema, creo yo, es que el modelo de datos tiene que ser informado del lenguaje que se obtuvo en el dispositivo y eso no está en su lógica (o al menos yo no lo veo contemplado). No veo cómo se relaciona el dato obtenido del dispositivo con las clases de su modelo de datos, por tanto, no se puede decidir nada, porque esa información no es recogida ni valorada en ningún momento. El problema por tanto es en el planteamiento lógico del problema. Se determina que el dispositivo está en inglés, o en español, o en chino o en lo que sea, pero ¿qué se hace luego con eso?

Comment: Mira esta pregunta, para que te des una idea, como obtener el idioma del dispositivo y traerte el contenido en ese idioma, en este caso use base de datos mysql https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132634/obtener-c%C3%B3digo-de-idioma-del-dispositivo-para-cargar-tabla-mysql-multi-idioma

Comment: Ahi agregué una posible solución para recuperar el mensaje basado en un idioma. Me parece que el problema principal es como están estructuradas las clases. @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la clase Dat_json podes agregarle métodos para recuperar los datos pasándole como parámetro el idioma que determinaste del dispositivo.

Luego fijate que las clases Es y En tienen la misma estructura, por eso te simplificaría usar una clase Idioma para esa estructura, lo mismo con las de fallo.

Esta es una alternativa. De la misma forma un otro método podría devolver el mensaje de fallo o acierto pasando el idioma y si se trata de un fallo o acierto.

```
public class Dat_json{
  private dobule decimalHola;
  private boolean boleanoHola;
  private int enteroHola;
  private Idiomas idiomas;
  private String mensajeHola;

  public Idioma getIdioma(String idiomaDispositivo){
      switch(idiomaDispositivo){
          case "es": return idiomas.getEs();
          default: return idiomas.getEn();
      }
  }

  public Msg getMsg(String idiomaDispositivo, String tipoMensaje){
      Idioma idiomaDeterminado = getIdioma(idiomaDispositivo);
      return idiomaDeterminado.getMsg(tipoMensaje);
  }

  // Getters y Setters
}

public class Idiomas{
  private Idioma en;
  private Idioma es;

  // Getters y Setters
}

public class Idioma{
  @SerializedName("msg_Fallo")
  Msg msgFallo;
  @SerializedName("msg_Correcto")
  Msg msgCorrecto;

  public Msg getMessage(String tipoMensaje){
    switch(tipoMensaje){
        case 'fallo': return msgFallo;
        case 'correcto' return msgCorrecto;
        default: return null;
    }
  }

  // Getter y Setter
}

public class Msg{
  String titulo;
  String mensaje;
  // Getters y Setters
}
```

Como se usa?

Supongamos que determinaste que el dispositivo está en español y guardas

```
String idiomaDisp = "es";
```

Cuando recibes el json, lo deserelias con Gson().

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Dat_json datJson= gson.fromJson(json, Dat_json.class);
```

Para obtener el idioma con los mensajes:

```
Idioma idiomaConMensajes = datJson.getIdioma(idiomaDisp);
```

Para obtener el mensaje de fallo:

```
Msg msgDeFallo = datJson.getMsg(idiomaDisp, "fallo");
```

Comment: Juan, pero aquí falta algo, a mi juicio. La clase `Idioma` tiene que tener un *setter* a la cual pasarle el idioma que se obtuvo del dispositivo. En ese *setter*  hay que verificar si el dato recibido está entre los idiomas que maneja el modelo de datos o no, y si no está hay que setearle el idioma por defecto. Eso es lo que llevo comentando hace un rato y que parece que no se llega a entender.

Comment: Lo pensé y también se puede así, el tema es que esta clase se instancia con Gson (como el atributo no viene (se determina en el dispositivo), me imagino que simplemente queda null), y hay que acordarse de setearlo después de desearializar. En esta otra solución el idioma del dispositivo se pasa como argumento en cada llamada. Las dos formas son viables pero me incliné por esta para no meter el atributo que no viaja.